# Group data by week and transpone by week day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

I have a table with data about hours logged against tasks like so:
Table1

```
| TaskID | DateRec    | Hours |
| 1      | 2017-10-08 | 3.5   |
| 1      | 2017-10-09 | 1     |
| 2      | 2017-10-09 | 5     |
| 1      | 2017-10-17 | 2.4   |
| 2      | 2017-10-17 | 2     |
| 5      | 2017-10-18 | 0.5   |
| 5      | 2017-10-19 | 2     |
```

The combination of TaskID and DateRec is always unique. Suppose my working week starts on Sunday, which means that '2017-10-08' would be the first day of Week 1, and '2017-10-15' would be the first day of Week 2 and so on. I need to group my Hours by TaskID and Week they were logged on, and then for each separate week transpone the Hours into seven columns by week day, from Day 1 to Day 7, like so:

```
                 (10-08) (10-09) (10-10) (10-11) (10-12) (10-13) (10-14)
(Task 1, Week 1) (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)
(Task 2, Week 1) (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)
                 (10-15) (10-16) (10-17) (10-18) (10-19) (10-20) (10-21)
(Task 1, Week 2) (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)
(Task 2, Week 2) (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)     (h)
...
```

So that in my example it would be:

```
    | TaskID | Week Start Date | Day1 | Day2 | Day3 | Day4 | Day5 | Day6 | Day7 |
    | 1      | 2017-10-08      | 3.5  | 1    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
    | 2      | 2017-10-08      | NULL | 5    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
    | 1      | 2017-10-15      | NULL | NULL | 2.4  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
    | 2      | 2017-10-15      | NULL | NULL | 2    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
    | 5      | 2017-10-15      | NULL | NULL | NULL | 0.5  | 2    | NULL | NULL |
```

Is it possible to do with SQL, and how exactly? Note: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select TaskID
              ,WeekBeg = DateAdd(DAY,1-DatePart(WEEKDAY,DateRec),DateRec)
              ,Item    = Concat('Day',DatePart(WEEKDAY,DateRec))
              ,Hours
         From  YourTable
      ) A
 Pivot (sum([Hours]) For [Item] in ([Day1],[Day2],[Day3],[Day4],[Day5],[Day6],[Day7]) ) p
```

**Returns**

(can't reload image ... `DateRec` was renamed to `WeekBeg`)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That will solve my problem. You didn't even have to use GROUP BY clause!

Comment: @B.Sverediuk Nope.  The sum in the PIVOT will do that for you.  :)